# exporting report to html format

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using *JasperReports API* to print reports on the browser. I have many formats to export the report to but mainly I am concern with my HTML. I am using the following code to export my report to HTML:

```
JRExporter exporter = null;
exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
exporter.exportReport();
```

This code is printing the output as following('images' even when there are none in my jrxml file):

[image: sample report]

As *Eclipse* showed me that JRExporter is deprecated, I did some research and found that now we use 'Exporter' to export. I am trying to use Exporter in my code to remove this error but can't find anyway I can write my jasperPrint file to the output Stream.

New code:

```
Exporter exporter = null;
exporter = new HtmlExporter();
```

> http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/HtmlExporter.html#exportReportToWriter()

some of my code in jrxml is as follows for reference:

```
<title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="219" y="28" width="194" height="40" uuid="44028360-543f-4352-a028-9e262bb24347"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="24"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Project Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="119" y="41" width="100" height="20" uuid="1f6ca9e9-92d5-41e5-9e8d-cd6ede8bfa25"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Project Status]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="41" width="100" height="20" uuid="6059b496-7ff9-4156-836b-f91436b8e79c"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Aldon Number]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
```

Comment: You can find samples in *JasperReports* distribution pack. For example, *NoPageBreakApp* (jasperreports-5.6.0\demo\samples\nopagebreak\src\)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all dont use `JRHtmlExporter()`. It's deprecated. I got images when I was using `HtmlExporter()`. Then I started using the following statements:

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter;
// ...
HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();
```

My coding for HTML is

```
HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint); 
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream); 
exporter.exportReport();
```

Answer (score 0):

try using with JRXhtmlExporter();

```
JRExporter exporter = new JRXhtmlExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
exporter.exportReport();
```